# A solution for developing a web game client for iphone and ipad…

Tags: web

We have just finished developing a web game using flex + flash + python and now we want to make a client app for the iphone/ipad device [just like this one](http://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/id434201999?mt=8)

Since we have had no such experience I hope someone has done this might give us some hint or suggestions.

PS:I got some advice from other websites saying that I can do it as follows:
1.Re-write those as script (logic stuff) with objC (I agree with this)
2.Use html5 (which I do not understand quite well, does this mean that I need to re-write those MXML files with html5?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Re-write the app in Objective-c would be a better choice, if you want performance.

If you want to port it to Android as well, then you might want to take a look at other solutions such as Corona SDK, Unity or Monkey.

If you are not comfortable using Objective-C, Corona SDK should be a better choice. The structure is similar to flash display object list, so it should be easier for Flash developer to understand. You also have a choice to deploy it to Android later if you want to.